# |Ubuntu 16.04| -- booting from USB -- used boot-repair -- error: can't find command 'drivemap'. error: invalid EFI file path

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

update: ran a boot-repair, not sure what it does or if it helps

http://paste2.org/VNvMVOY0

i restarted and picked the option that was added (see below) but nothing changed

have no idea why any of these problems are occuring, i never really even used this laptop any after installing ubuntu....

--

- my laptop is not booting from usb
- 'system setup' options goes to a black screen then back to the grub menu

after i edited a grub file -- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Chainloading

and try to boot from that new option added, i get

error: can't find command 'drivemap'.
error: invalid EFI file path.

more background context -- https://askubuntu.com/questions/861870/on-ubuntu-16-04-cant-boot-a-usb-containing-an-iso-on-startup

Comment: You show UEFI secure boot still on. And  a Mint installer ISO but Ubuntu install? Better to use Ubuntu installer if repairing Ubuntu. With Secure boot on, you may need to turn on allow USB boot in UEFI (you may need that anyway). Script mentions RAID? Is that really Intel SRT. Have you turned that off and removed RAID meta-data on drives? And then is drive set to AHCI mode in UEFI. Older info, may still apply: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2199382

Comment: im trying to install mint. the link shows that i can't boot from usb.

Answer (score 1):

Your manual `External drive (on hd1) if no eSATA drive connected. edit if necessary` entry uses syntax for a BIOS-mode boot; however, your computer is booting in EFI/UEFI mode. GRUB can't switch boot modes, so the entry you've created won't work.

It's not 100% clear what your problem is. GRUB isn't really designed to redirect the boot process to an external boot medium, although it *can* do that job if you configure it in exactly the right way. To boot from an external disk, you should normally use the computer's built-in boot manager, which you can access by hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key on most systems. (How to get to the built-in boot manager varies greatly from one computer to another, so I can't be more specific.) If the external medium is bootable in BIOS mode but not in EFI mode, you may need to activate the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; aka "BIOS support," "legacy mode," or something similar) in the firmware's setup utility, too.

You might also want to look into my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) which scans for boot loaders every time it starts. Thus, rEFInd can usually detect bootable USB drives when they're available. (There are limitations, though. Sometimes you must hit Esc to have rEFInd re-scan for boot loaders, since USB drives might be registered slowly. Also, rEFInd is an EFI-only tool by default on UEFI PCs; to boot BIOS-mode boot loaders, you must edit the `scanfor` line in the `refind.conf` file to activate BIOS/CSM/legacy support.)

If the problem is that you can't boot into Ubuntu, then please edit your question to more clearly state the problem, or post a new question.

Comment: the link shows that i can't access the laptop's built-in boot manager

Comment: Are you saying that rEFInd does not provide an option to boot into the firmware? If so, then your EFI must be an older one that doesn't provide the interface rEFInd uses to implement this feature. If you mean something else, then please clarify.

Comment: is there a simple, easy to read, step by step page/guide on how to install, use, etc. this rEFInd thing? too many confusing & unnecessary words. just the plain & relevant steps

Comment: ??? i can't do anything with the laptop now cos ubuntu messed up something basic like the boot feature